# Is the set $C = \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 < \ln(1+x_4^2)\}$ open or closed or neither?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm using the following definition of closed and open sets:

- Set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if $\forall x \in C\ \exists   
     \varepsilon > 0: U_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset C$.
- Set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed if it contains all its limit
  points.

I don't have much idea of how to tackle this exercise. This is what I've done so far (almost nothing):

Let $x_4$ be fixed, such that $x_4 \ll 1$. Then we have that

$$0 < x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 < \ln(1+x_4^2) \approx x_4^2$$

it follows that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: U_{\varepsilon}(x_4) \not\subset C$. So $C$ is not open.

I have the feeling that $C$ is not closed either, but I don't know how to prove that or show the opposite.

Comment: There's a typo at the 2nd bullet point.  Set $C$ is closed.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Ups! I fixed it (:

Comment: I disagree with this statement "it follows that $∀ε>0:U_ε(x_4)⊄C∀ε>0:U_ε(x_4)⊄C.$"  Regarding is C closed.... I say (0,0,0,0) is a limit point of C and it is not in C.  I will leave it to you to prove that statement.

Comment: Your inference that $C$ is not open from your statement$0 < x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 < \ln(1+x_4^2) \approx x_4^2$ is wrong.  $C$ must be open as it is the inverse of an open set under a continuous mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$
f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \ln(1+x_4^2) - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2.
$$

Show that $f$ is continuous and see what you can conclude about $C = f^{-1}[(0, \infty)]$.

Comment: @Surb I admit that this way is more elegant and time-saving than mine, so I upvoted.  Since this solution pops up while I was struggling with the set equalities, I kept on typing until the end.  IMHO, answers ([tag:general-topology]) problems can assume some basic well-known facts like the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

### $C$ is open

First, make $x_4$ the subject of the inequality in the definition of $C$ (so as to make use of preimage).

\begin{array}{rrl}
& x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 <& \ln(1+x_4^2) \\
\iff& \exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) <& 1+x_4^2 \\
\iff& \exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1 <& x_4^2 \\
\iff& x_4 >& \sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1} \text{ or } \\
&x_4 <& -\sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1} \tag1\label1
\end{array}

Let $f_1:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ be defined as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto-\sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1}$ and
$f_2:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ be defined as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto\sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1}$.
They are well-defined since $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \ge 0$, so $\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) \ge 1$.  This allows us to take square root.
Next, observe that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are *continuous* on $\Bbb R^3$ since they're composition of elementary functions.
Rewrite the definition of $C$ using these two *continuous* functions to see the openness.

\begin{align}
C =& \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 < \ln(1+x_4^2)\} \\
\stackrel{\eqref{1}}=& \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_4 > \sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1} \text{ or } \\ & x_4 < -\sqrt{\exp(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 1}\} \\
=& \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_4 > f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) \text{ or } x_4 < f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3)\} \\
=& \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_4 < f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) \} \cup \{( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_4 > f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) \} \\
=& \bigcup_{x_4 \in \Bbb R} \{( x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_4 < f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) \} \cup \{( x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_4 > f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) \} \\
=& \bigcup_{x_4 \in \Bbb R} f_1^{-1}((-\infty,x_4)) \cup f_2^{-1}((x_4,+\infty))
\end{align}

Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous, for each $x_4 \in \Bbb R$, the first and the second sets in the last equality are open.  Hence $C$ is open.

### $C$ is *not* closed

Expand @DougM's idea.  Consider $c_n = (0,0,0,\frac1n) \in \Bbb R^4, n \in \Bbb N$.  The points $c_n$ are in $C$ since $0^2+0^2+0^2 = 0 < \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$.  $(c_n)$ converges to $(0,0,0,0)$ so $(0,0,0,0) \in \overline{C}$, but $(0,0,0,0) \notin C$ since $\ln(1+0^2) = 0$, so the strictly inequality in the definition of $C$ *doesn't* hold.